# Facebook display: 'page' not working with FB.ui and popups are blocked by the browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I know that iframes are not allowed by facebook for unauthorized applications but i can't get display: 'page' to work with FB.ui either. The only display mode that is working is popup. Both the login and FB.ui dialogs are being blocked by the popup blocker even though they are working on every other website with facebook login. The popup blocker kicks in even when the FB.login and FB.ui functions are called by a user click. This is really, really annoying. So please help me out.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>
<script>
function xyz() 
{
FB.init({ 
appId:'113381182103752', cookie:true, 
status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true     
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if(response.status=="connected")
{
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="User is connected";
}
else if(response.status=="unknown")
{
FB.login(function(response) {
if(response.authResponse)
{
var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
document.getElementById("tokendiv").innerHTML=token;
}
});
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="User is logged out";
}
else if(response.status=="not_authorized")
{
FB.ui({
client_id: '113381182103752',
method: 'oauth',
redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/test3.php',
response_type: 'token',
display: 'page'
});    
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="User is connected but app is not authorized";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Error";
}
});
}
</script> 
<div id="tokendiv"></div>
<div id="status"></div> 
<button onclick="xyz()">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1) display: 'popup' is mandatory for method: 'oauth' or FB.login for javascript SDK because of security (clickjacking and phishing). I'd suggest to use FB.login anyway to get permissions or to authenticate because it is more convenient.

2) your popup is blocked by browser because FB.login is deeply nested in your javascript call stack, though user initiated. It has to be user initiated plus try to redesign you code so FB.login is not nested.

Comment: Yes i replaced FB.ui with FB.login because as you say it is more convenient. I built some more code and everything is fine except the popup problem so i'll try to amend the code and report back here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using FB.login either instead of FB.getLoginStatus or instead of FB.ui to handle the popup.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // user is logged in and has permissions
  }
}, {scope:'email'});
```

Comment: No luck. It was already blocking the popup generated by FB.login nested in the FB.getLoginStatus function. Maybe it's that the popup blocker has blacklisted the page on localhost because it wasn't blocking yesterday. But what about page: 'display', why does that not work? Can anyone test the code on their own machine and tell if they're having the same issues?